# USA citizen/passport holder

Tags: visas, transit

USA citizen with American passport: would I need a transit visa at Narita Airport on my way to/from Australia?

Answer (score 0):

No, US citizens transiting in Japan do not need a visa.

[Source](https://jp.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/local-resources-of-u-s-citizens/transiting-through-narita/)

(But I would make sure you have the right clearance for Australia)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a visa to transit Japan (or enter for up to 90 days), but do require an [online passport registration](https://www.eta.immi.gov.au/ETAS3/etas) for AUD 20 in order to enter Australia.